# how to copy returned array directly into another array?

Tags: c, arrays, return-value

I have been learning arrays, but theres one thing that I cant figure out.
I borrowed two books for C and looked online, but found no solution.

My function timesTen multiplies every array elemenet that I have by 10,
then returns pointer of that array back function main()

How can I copy array a[2] directly in array x[2]?

I would usually use for loop, but I cant, because arguments are in two different functions.

Solution has probably got something to do with pointers, so feel free to post sollution here, but is there any way around them aswell?

Heres the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int timesTen(int a[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
    printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    a[i]*=10;
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int x[2];
    int a[2]={10,50};

// i know here's an error, but how do I fix it? I cant put x[0]=timesTen(a[0])
    x[2]  =  timesTen(a);
//also what if there is array a[10], and I want to copy it in x[5] 
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
        printf("%d\n", x[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Was it your intent to have your products *separate* from your input data? If so, you can pass your output array just as you're passing your input array and fill it in your function as you compute your products. If you just want to overwrite the old operands with the results, passing x isn't needed (and by the looks of it, neither is the variable in `main()` either if that is the case).

Comment: _what if there is array a[10], and I want to copy it in x[5]?_ What if I have 10 litres of water and I want to fit it in a 5-litre container?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to understand is the distinction between arrays and pointers. When you declare your two arrays in `main()`, you allocate two times memory for two integers. That's fine. But in C, you simply cannot pass arrays around (as in: implicitly allocate a new slap of memory and copy the data of the source array into this memory region). Instead, any array identifier will *decay to a pointer to the first element of the array* in almost all situation. So when you write

```
int x[2];
int a[2]={10,50};
timesTen(a);
```

this code is precisely equivalent to

```
int x[2];
int a[2]={10,50};
timesTen(&a[0]);
```

So, why does that not clash with your declaration of `timesTen()`? Because array parameters in function declarations decay right there, on the spot, into a pointer! So, your function declaration is precisely equivalent to this one:

```
int timesTen(int* a) {
```

This is one of the least understood features of the C language, and admittedly, it is hard to wrap your brain around this, but once you understand what pointer decay means, you will be much more at ease using pointers and arrays.

So, back to your question. Since you passed only a pointer to your array to `timesTen()`, and since you modify this array, the changes are directly visible in `main()`. There are two ways to achieve the behavior you want:

1. You can change the definition of `timesTen()` to copy the data into a destination array:

   ```
   void timesTen(int size, int* source, int* dest) {
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) dest[i] = 10*source[i];
   }

   int main() {
       int x[2];
       int a[2]={10,50};
       timesTen(2, a, x);    //pointer decay!
       //x now contains {100, 500}
   }
   ```
2. You can copy the data into the destination array before calling your function to modify the destination array:

   ```
   void timesTen(int size, int* data) {
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) data[i] = 10*data[i];
   }

   int main() {
       int x[2];
       int a[2]={10,50};
       memcpy(x, a, sizeof(a));    //the sizeof operator is one of only two places where no pointer decay happens!
       timesTen(2, x);    //pointer decay!
       //x now contains {100, 500}
   }
   ```

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) dest[i] = 10*source[i];
Im not sure how it works for you, but I cant initialize integer in for loop. It says I need C99 version or something. Whats the difference + should I get it?

Comment: Yes, it's a part of the C99 standard. With `gcc`, you can compile C99 code by using the `-std=c99` flag on the command line. However, while you are at it, you should probably use `-std=c11` instead, as the C11 standard is the current one. You can also switch on GNU extensions to the language using `-std=gnu11`, this however has the disadvantage that you can write code that does not compile with other compilers.

Comment: But I dont see many more useful features than just for(INT i;;)
is it truly better to download/use this mode?

Comment: As I said, C11 is the current standard of the language itself. As such, you can expect any up to date compiler to be able to compile C11 code. It's just that, for some obscure reason, gcc still defaults to the C90 standart (plus GNU extensions), which is plain outdated. I would always use at least `-std=c11`, there is simply no point in writing code in an outdated language. Heck, C11 will probably be outdated in 15 years as well...

Answer (score 1):

In the function `timesTen`, since `a` is an array, each modification made to it in the function is also done to the parameter you passed (call by address not by value). Therefore you don't need to returns anything.

```
void timesTen(int a[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) a[i]*=10;
}
```

And you just call it by:

```
timesTen(a);
```

Comment: oh sorry I didnt know my bad :/ wont hapen again

Comment: @user3272749 : No problem ! I'm just trying to improve your skill as a SO user :-).

Comment: I'd thank you if it wasnt agains the rules of this site ;) hehe

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
 timesTen(a);
 memmove(x, a, 2 * sizeof(x[0]));
```

instead of

```
 x[2]  =  timesTen(a);
```

Note that your function does not need to return anything, because it is modifying the array on its original place. In C if you have an array parameter, it means that only a pointer is passed, not the whole array.

Comment: Well that'd probably work, but I'd like a simpler solution, the one that I could think about myself and not just forget in a month (like this memmove function).

Comment: Note, that this will leave the array `a` modified, which might not be what you want. If you want the data in `a` unchanged, do the `memmove()`/`memcpy()` before calling `timesTen(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

in main function:

```
   int *p;
   int i;

   p = timesTen(a);
   for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
   {
       printf( "%d\n",*(p + i)); // here you can print the values returned from your function 
   }
```

Comment: Well thats exactly what I was looking for. Thats solves my issue :)
but there is no way around pointers in my case?
EDIT : solved below

Comment: You need @hivert's solution, you just don't need second array

Comment: Then i guess, i can ask for an upvote for solving your issue.

Comment: I dont have the reputation yet :D You can upvote me so I can upvote people soon i guess

Answer (score 0):

Through pointers you could have eaisly managed it

```
main ()
     { 
        int a[ 2 ];
        int *ptr = timesTen(a);
        for ( int i=0; i<2 ; i++)
              {
                  printf("%d",ptr[i]);
              }
```

And as far as

```
  x[2] = timesTen(a);
```

Is concerned note that x[2] will give "value at 2nd adress from adrees of base that is x"
And it is not a variable but it is a value and you cant assign to a value.
Technically x[2] is not a lvalue.